# Python: Get JSON objects from Web API based on filtered values

Tags: python, json, api

I'm very new to JSON and Web API. I'm working with the following API: https://docs.opendota.com/

What I am trying to do is to retrieve all matches with a certain *leagueid*. The issue arises when I have to loop through all the *matchIds*. I would like to retrieve only the matches where the `leagueid` equals to a certain value to speed up the data retrieval. Is there a possibility to apply the *leagueid* filter on the loop and skip looping through all matches?

```
import requests


theleagueid = 10197
startinggameid= 4182682702
endinggameid = 4192237735
matchidlist = []

for x in range (startinggameid, endinggameid):
    try:
        leaguecheck = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}".format(x)).json()['leagueid']
    except KeyError:
        print('')
    if leaguecheck == theleagueid:
        getmatch = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}".format(x)).json()['match_id']
        matchidlist.append(getmatch)
print(matchidlist)
```